# Drag and Drop UITableViewCell which contains custom UIView in cell.content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I am newbie on this, as titled, would like to implement custom drag & drop in `UITableView`, while each `UITableViewCell` content (cell.content?) will contains a custom `UIView`. E.g. Row1-cell-CustomUIView1, Row2-cell-CustomUIView2. Which custom `UIView` added to which row is based on user selection on that row and a button click. Now imagine you have 4 custom `UIViews`, i.e. being added into 4 rows/cells in the `UITableView` and how can I implement the drag and drop of these `CustomUIView`? Note, each custom UIView may not be the same as typical table cell. i.e. custom UIView1 layout/design is different from custom `UIView2`. Implement in swift, Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the mainImgView to handle the dragging:

```
var draggableImage : UIImageView!
var mainImgView : UIImageView!
var trashImgView : UIImageView!
var dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter : CGPoint?
var panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer!

panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleDrag:")
mainImgView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func handleDrag(nizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
   if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
      self.draggableImage = UIImageView(image: mainImgView.image)
      self.draggableImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
      self.draggableImage.center = mainImgView.center
      self.draggableImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
      self.draggableImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
      self.draggableImage.alpha = 0.5

      self.view.addSubview(self.draggableImage)
      self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sself.draggableImage)

      let locationInView = nizer.locationInView(self.draggableImage.superview)
      dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - self.draggableImage.center.x, y: locationInView.y - self.draggableImage.center.y)

      self.draggableImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
      self.draggableImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
      self.draggableImage.layer.shadowRadius = 6

      return
  }

  if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed {
     let locationInView = nizer.locationInView(self.draggableImage.superview)
     UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) {
        self.draggableImage.center = CGPoint(x: locationInView.x - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.x,
            y: locationInView.y - self.dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter!.y)
    }

      var checkAddToBag : Bool = CGRectContainsRect(self.draggableImage.frame, self.trashImgView.frame)

      if (checkAddToBag == true){
        self.trashImgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.trashImgView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    } else {
        self.trashImgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        self.trashImgView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
      }

      return
   }

   if nizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
      var checkAddToBag : Bool = CGRectContainsRect(self.draggableImage.frame, self.trashImgView.frame)

      self.trashImgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
      self.trashImgView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0

      dragStartPositionRelativeToCenter = nil

      self.draggableImage.removeFromSuperview()
      self.draggableImage = nil

      return
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mee. Got couple of questions, will this also apply if each custom UIViews with different height? (the width should be the same for every custom UIView in each row). Secondly, if each of this custom UIView is editable (e.g. a custom UIView in a cell, maybe contain text box and able to take picture/upload image into it), it can still move around I assume, will the table row/list order maintain? How the data inside each custom UIView should be held in such case?

Comment: If I don't exprss very clear, the whole point is just like the "Reminder" app in iphone, (1) which able to add new/append the new one to the bottom, one after another on request, (2) able to delete on request and (3) able to drag and drop (4) maintain/retain the re-arranged order for later use properly.